# R Markdown - How to read every day data from external URL and execute the R code each time?

Tags: r, r-markdown, github-pages

I made a html web in Github Pages from a R Markdown. I need reread a dataset from a URL every day and execute the R code in the R Markdown each time, but I failed to achieve it. The dataset change every day so it is necessary reread it every day. I try to invalidate the cache every day with this in the R code chunk R Markdown:

````
```{r echo= FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache=TRUE, cache.extra = Sys.Date()}
````

But I failed to read the changes in the external dataset and the data is always the same that it was the day I created the HTML output in R Studio. Is the first time that I use a R Markdown so probabily I am doing something very wrong. Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Comment: How do you read the dataset? Can you provide an example?

Comment: url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"
cvirus <- read.csv(url, header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)